# Why git commit command is not working by using java using the jproc library?

Tags: java, git

I am trying to write a code to commit with git but it is working sometimes and not working the other time.
Here is the code for it:

```
ProcResult result = new ProcBuilder("git")
                .withArg("init")
                .withWorkingDirectory(new File(dir))
                .run();

        result = new ProcBuilder("git")
                .withArgs("add",".")
                .run();
        result = new ProcBuilder("git")
                .withArgs("commit","-m").withArg("1st commit")
                .run();
        System.out.println("Successfully commited");
```

I tried something like the given code below but it still doesn't work:

```
result = new ProcBuilder("git")
            .withArgs("commit","-m").withArg(""+(char)34+"1st commit"+(char)34+"")
            .run();
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.buildobjects.process.ExternalProcessFailureException: External process 'git commit -m '1st commit'' returned 1 after 126ms

    at org.buildobjects.process.Proc.<init>(Proc.java:126)
    at org.buildobjects.process.ProcBuilder.run(ProcBuilder.java:205)
    at ProjectInitializerAutomation.ProjectInitializerAutomation.Local.command(Local.java:90)
    at ProjectInitializerAutomation.ProjectInitializerAutomation.Local.createFolder(Local.java:58)
    at ProjectInitializerAutomation.ProjectInitializerAutomation.Local.create(Local.java:39)
    at ProjectInitializerAutomation.ProjectInitializerAutomation.Driver.main(Driver.java:21)
```